# When creating criteria in grails isNull is not picking up null records

Tags: grails

I'm using createCriteria to build the list of search results.  The inList is working fine but I can't get the optional isNull to work.  In the database I can see there are records with a null value in the column but they are not getting selected.  The AdoptionAgreement domain is an enum.  isEmpty doesn't work I get a grails exception for that.

```
   def adoptionAgreementCriteria = {
        if (params.adoptionAgreement) {
            inList('adoptionAgreement', params.list('adoptionAgreement').collect { AdoptionAgreement.valueOf(it)} )
            or {
                isNull('adoptionAgreement')
            }
        }
    }
```

What doesn't look right about this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look right that you have only one thing within the closure passed to the `or`.

When you use `or` you need to include all the terms inside the curly braces:

```
or {
    option1
    option2
}
```

which means: option1 OR option2.

[The first example in the documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/GORM.html#criteria) has an `or`:

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
def results = c {
    between("balance", 500, 1000)
    eq("branch", "London")
    or {
        like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
        like("holderFirstName", "Barney%")
    }
    maxResults(10)
    order("holderLastName", "desc")
}
```

this retrieves rows where the balance is in the given range and the branch is the specified one and (holder name is 'Fred' or holder name is 'Barney').

Comment: Yes that was it.  I needed both statements inside the or closure.  I thought  the syntax was like I initially listed it.